# Problema com navegação entre telas IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tabbarcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver um problema, onde utilizo um menu suspenso *SWRevealViewController* em meu projeto IOS utilizando a linguagem objective-c, em meu app eu tenho um *UITabbarController* contendo 4 *tabbarItem* onde cada um tem um *UINavigationViewController* responsável pela navegação entre as telas , mas o *UITabbarController* está como *rootViewController* então eu até consigo navegar entre as telas mas utilizando apenas o *navigationBar* ao clicar em algum *tabbarItem* o app simplesmente para e não consigo mas navegar entre as telas isso ocorre também com *UITableView*, alguém teria a solução?

Segue a função de inicialização do AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

Cardapio* vc1 = [[Cardapio alloc] init];
Carrinho* vc2 = [[Carrinho alloc] init];
Configuracao* vc3 = [[Configuracao alloc] init];
ViewController* viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
Menu* menu = [[Menu alloc] init];

UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];



UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menu];

SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

vc1.title = @"Cardápio";
vc2.title = @"Carrinho";
vc3.title = @"Configuração";
mainRevealController.title=@"Principal";

vc2.tabBarItem.badgeValue=@"0";


vc1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico1"];
vc2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico2"];
vc3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico3"];
mainRevealController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico4"];


UINavigationController* n1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
UINavigationController* n2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
UINavigationController* n3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc3];

NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mainRevealController, n1,n2,n3, nil];

_tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
_tabBarController.delegate=self;

window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro no console? Tente isolar o problema, removendo o máximo possível de código de forma que o problema ainda ocorra e poste o código resultante.

Comment: App para em que sentido? Ele não mostra nada? Ele da erro? Ele fecha seu app? Pode detalhar um pouco mais a falha por favor?